# Use host network on docker swarm versoin 17.03

Tags: docker, networking

[This links](http://In%20Docker%2017.06%20and%20higher,%20you%20can%20also%20use%20a%20host%20network%20for%20a%20swarm%20service,) says:

> In Docker 17.06 and higher, you can also use a host network for a swarm service, by passing --network host to the docker container create command.

But I'm using docker version 17.03 which I cannot upgrade. Is there a workaround?

I want the containers created using `docker stack` to have access to the host's network.

Comment: The workaround is to upgrade. Why do you expect that a version lacking the feature you want can use the feature you want?

Comment: I was hoping there was another way to do it even if it was "harder"..